# How to parse mathematical formulae from strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

I want to write a program that takes an string like `x^2+1` and understand it.

I want to ask the user to enter her/his function and I want to be able to process and understand it. Any Ideas?

```
char s[100];

s <- "x*I+2"

x=5;
I=2;
res=calc(s);
```

I think it could be done by something like string analyses but I think Its so hard for me.

I have another Idea and that is using tcc in main program and doing a realtime compile and run and delete a seprated program (or maybe function) that has the `string s` in it.

and I will create a temp file every time and ask tcc to compile it and run it by exec or similar syntax.

```
/*tmp.cpp:*/
#include <math.h>
void main(/*input args*/){
return x*I+2;
}
```

the `tmp.cpp` will created dynamically.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Compiling a dynamic C++ file is a *great* solution... for another problem.

Comment: @spraff - would you mind explain what you mean?

Comment: Well if you were writing an IDE for a plugin system and wanted to compile and test the modules on the fly, then yeah, do this. Otherwise it's a using sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 2):

use a [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Sample: it's in german, but a small and powerfull solution
look [here](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/p1642138)

[here](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/p1989618) is exactly what You are searching for. Change the function read_varname to detect a variable like 'x' or 'I'.

Answer (score 2):

I use with success , [function parser](http://warp.povusers.org/FunctionParser/)

from www it looks like it supports also  `std::complex`, but I never used it

Answer (score 1):

As luck would have it, [I recently wrote one](https://github.com/spraff/monolith)!

Look for {,include/}lib/MathExpression/Term. It handles complex numbers but you can easily adapt it for plain old floats.

The licence is GPL 2.

---

The theory in brief, when you have an expression like

```
X*(X+2)
```

Your highest level parser can parse expressions of the form A + B + C... In this case A is the whole expression.

You recurse to parse an operator of higher precedence, A * B * C... In this case A is X and B is (X+2)

Keep recursing until you're parsing either basic tokens such as X or hit an opening parenthesis, in which case push some kind of stack to track where your are and recurse into the parentheses with the top-level low-precedence parser.

I recommend you use RAII and throw exceptions when there are parse errors.

Comment: thanks. I know but I wish that if there is a way to let the user use full syntax of c++ cause: think about this the user wants to have this: `sqrt(sin(X))+tan(t);` or some more complex things. What is RAII?

Comment: My MathExpression::Term class does exactly that. RAII is Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, it basically means all resource ownership is controlled by constructors and destructors, which is necessary for exception safety (and a good idea for other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you expect. It's too complex to give the code as answer, but the general idea is not very complex. It's not out of reach to code, even for a normal hobbyist programmer.

You need to define grammar, tokenize string, recognize operators, constants and variables.
Probably put expression into a tree. Make up a method for substituting the variables... and you can evaluate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some kind of a parser. The easiest way to have math operations parsable is to have them written in [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). You can, however, write your own parser using parser libraries, like [Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) from boost or [Yacc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO.html#toc5)