# How to evaluate a string which contains code and run it in C++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm looking for a way to parse a string for any valid C++ code, and then run it somehow. In particular, math functions like `sin()` or `cos()`.

The basic method of parsing every single character doesn't extend to expressions with multiple math functions.

Is there a way to parse and evaluate code from within a std::string?

Comment: Not in the language standard, you'd need an interpreter

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your comment

Comment: [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe http://chaiscript.com/ could be a good fit aswell.

Comment: to execute arbitrary code there are a lot of duplicate questions [Convert string to code at run time c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18766048/995714), [is it possible to make a function execute code from a string on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225124/995714), [execute C++ from String variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15841511/995714), [How to run c++ code from c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1541429/995714)

Comment: However just for doing math then it's a different problem [parsing math expression in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11703082/995714), [Evaluate Mathematical Function from String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9977045/995714), [How to parse mathematical formulae from strings in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969995/995714)...

Comment: @phuclv Thank you, I'll read up on the Shunting yard algorithm.